# Visa extension in India for a baby U.S citizen

Tags: india, us-citizens, visa-extensions

I'm an Indian citizen living in the United States on a dependent visa. My 5 month old son, was born in the U.S and now we are in India.
On arrival, the stamp in the baby's passport says something like, the stay should not exceed 180 days. (Until May 2020).

I have applied for a Visa extension online, for the baby, and received a certificate in the email (without any fee or personal visit to the office).
It says -

> Service Granted - Registration Certificate/Residential Permit Valid
>   until October 2023

I just wanted to know, if we wish to extend our stay even after 180 days (May 2020), is that RC is all that is needed to be produced at the airport when returning to the U.S.
Do we need any other certificates to be produced for the baby in India or the U.S.

Comment: Isn't the baby eligible for overseas citizenship of India?  Regardless, the only thing you'll need to show to US authorities is the baby's passport.  The baby could remain outside the US for 90 years and still be able to return with only a US passport (assuming US nationality law remains the same, of course).

Comment: @phoog OCIs are no longer visa-exempt for India until further notice (due to Covid-19) so that status has lost much of its power.

Comment: @Crazydre does that matter for someone who is currently in India?  The question is about traveling to the US.  It's just not clear whether it's about leaving India, entering the US, or both.  But it sounds like none of that will be happening in the immediate future, anyway.

Comment: @phoog Talking about why applying for it may not much make sense at this point. But I guess you're right

Comment: @phoog. It is for travelling back to the U.S. This question was posted long before the outbreak. I would like to know the option in general, when all this lockdown phase is over. Thank you

Comment: @Qwerty but are you asking about documents needed to leave India or to enter the US?  Both are part of "travelling back to the U.S."